# The type 'xxx' is defined in an asembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

As I recently updated a custom DLL file to version 1.0.3483.0, when I included that DLL file in the project, it required version 1.0.3478.

What are the steps I need to follow in order to update the DLL file in a project?

##### Visual Studio 2015 Error

[image: Visual Studio 2015 error]

##### DLL file version

[image: DLL file version]

The DLL file was removed and added, and the project was unloaded and reloaded, but it still does not work.

Comment: Hi, Is there any update in this issue?

Comment: As of 2023-02-16, this question is #2 in terms of [view rate among younger questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-for-newer-questions) (less than 2 years): about 3,000 views per day on average. Out of about 3,000,000 questions.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75167418/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element) to use the specified version.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                               publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                               culture="neutral" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                              newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select Properties.
2. Go to the Application tab and select Assembly Information.
3. In the Assembly Information dialog, enter the new version number in the Assembly Version text box.
4. Click OK.
5. Build the project to apply the changes.